# Twilio not including X-Twilio-Signature header in POST request to https address

Tags: twilio

As per https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security, Twilio should be including a "X-Twilio-Signature" header in requests sent to https addresses. However, the request sent to my application does not include such a header.
[Please see the screenshot of the request details from Twilio's debugger page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FRR1.png)

Comment: Which webook is this coming from?  Sms, voice, something else?

Comment: It's an sms webhook for a phone number

Comment: Just noticed the screenshot is showing the response headers which are what is being returned from your server.  Is the header listed under the Request headers, which would be the headers twilio is sending to you.

Comment: You're absolutely right; that was my oversight. I inspected the headers sent to my server and found that they included one called "HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE", which still differs from that in Twilio's documentation, but at least now I know where the problem lies. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Devin Rader pointed out, the Twilio debugger was showing the response headers sent from my server, rather than the request headers sent to my server. The actual request sent to my server contained a header called "HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE".